# Placing a variable into a PDO Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

is it possible to create a pdo query with a variable? Example:

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT (*) c FROM blogpages WHERE keywords LIKE '%test%' ";
```

then

```
$query = $db->query("$q");

$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

when i do this i get an error

> "Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C....."

i want to know is there a way to place the query in there as a variable because the query changes depending on how many OR statements are in the query

Comment: use this $query = $db->query($q); instead of $query = $db->query("$q");

Comment: i'm still receiving the same error

Comment: "Ask" [`var_export($db->errorInfo());`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) what went wrong with the query.

Comment: PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) c FROM blogpages WHERE keywords LIKE '%test%'' at line 1 )

Comment: The space between `Count` and `(*)` is the problem. Regardless of that the double.quotes in `$db->query("$q");` are superfluous.

Comment: thanks that worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

> PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a
>   PDOStatement object

And problem in your query with space `between count and (*)`

```
SELECT COUNT (*)..
            ^^
```

SO no need to fetch data just use

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM blogpages WHERE keywords LIKE '%test%' ";
foreach ($db->query($q) as $row) {
        print $row['c'] . "\t";
    }
```